# ajaxComplete - form submission / validation issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP page with a login form. When the form is clicked, back-end validation is performed and json returns the status of the login validation.

Code executed when clicking the submit button of the form :

```
// When DOM is ready
$(document).ready(function(){       
    // When the form is submitted
    $("#status > li > form").submit(function(){

        // Hide 'Submit' Button
        $('#submit').hide();

        // Clear the error messages if any
        $('#error_response').html("");

        // 'this' refers to the current submitted form 
        var str = $(this).serialize();

        var ran_no = new Date().getTime();                  
        str += "&ran="+ran_no;

        // -- Start AJAX Call --
        $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST", 
                url: "process.php",  // Send the login info to this page
                data: str, 
                dataType:'json',
                success: function(msg){
                    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){ 

                    // Hide Gif Spinning Rotator
                    $('#ajax_loading').hide();

                    // Show 'Submit' Button
                    $('#submit').show();

                    if(msg.error_array == "OK") // LOGIN OK?
                    {  
                    var login_response = '<li><div class="alert alert-success" id="ajax_response"><i class="icon-spinner icon-spin pull-left"></i> Succes...</div></li>';
                    // Replace the dropdownlist contents
                    $('#status').html(login_response); // Refers to 'status'
                    // After 3 seconds redirect the 
                    setTimeout('go_to_private_page()', 3000); 
                    }  
                    else // ERROR?
                     {  
                        var login_response = "";
                        $.each(msg.error_array,function(i,element)
                        {
                        login_response = "<div class=\"alert alert-error\">" + element + "<br>";
                        });
                        $('#ajax_response').html(login_response);
                     }  
                    });  
                    }  
                }); 
                // -- End AJAX Call --
        return false;
    }); // end submit event

    });
```

The php page that is being called for login validation returns a Json object

```
function procLogin(){
    global $session, $form;    
    /* Login attempt */

    // database call  
    $retval = $session->login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], isset($_POST['remember_me']));
    $results = array ();
    /* Login successful */
    if($retval){
        $results['error_array'] = array('OK');
        echo json_encode($results);
    }
    /* Login failed */
    else{
    $_SESSION['value_array'] = $_POST;
    $_SESSION['error_array'] = $form->getErrorArray();
    $results['value_array'] = $_POST;           //Holds submitted form field values 
    $results['error_array'] = $form->getErrorArray();   //Holds submitted form error messages  
    echo json_encode($results);
    }
}
```

When the user logs succesfully in from the first time, everything works ok.

In case the user enters an invalid password the first time and corrects it, he still gets the invalid password message on the second attempt.

The same code without using ajax / json works fine.

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It could be the caching issue. Try adding:

```
cache: false
```

to your Ajax call.

Comment: Thanks, I added the parameter, but no luck. When using Firebug to monitor the call to process.php, I do notice the call is the first time username=foouser&password=test123&sublogin=1&action=user_login&ran=1367612282272, and the second time when I test username=correctuser&password=test123&sublogin=1&action=user_login&ran=1367612286789 . So the call uses the updated form values.